# django - Altering form data after POST

Tags: django

I am trying to change the data after the user fills up a form. However, I would like to make it simple for front facing users to click on radio buttons but at the backend input the required information.

Here I am trying to obtain a date input, which I wanna give users a choice of 'TODAY' or 'ANOTHER DAY'. When 'TODAY' is selected, I want the database to capture the date as at that particular day. My code is as follows:

```
#models.py
DATE_CHOICES = (
    ('Today', 'Today'),
    ('Other days', 'Other days'),
)

class Mileage(models.Model):
        date = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices= DATE_CHOICES)

        def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
            return self.date

    class MileageForm(ModelForm):
        date = forms.ChoiceField(choices=DATE_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)

        class Meta:
            model = Mileage
            fields = ['date']

#views.py
def home(request):
form = MileageForm(request.POST or None)

context = {
        "form": form,
    }

if form.is_valid():
    if form.cleaned_data.get('date') == "Today":
        form.cleaned_data["date"]= time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    form.save()
    form = MileageForm()
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }

return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

I understand that the input is captured immediately on POST and in this case 'Today' was the defined choices. Is there a way to alter change 'Today' into the actual date itself when it saves into the database?

Comment: It would probably be much nicer to just have a `DateField` and a javascript button (or similar) that will set the value to `today`, otherwise just set its default to today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to alter the `POST` data.

Django forms work by taking the input data (usually `POST`) and converting them to python data via the `clean` mechanism. There are hooks for cleaning each field individually.

Thus your form's `clean_date` method could convert `'Today'` to `date.today()`. E.g.:

```
class MileageForm(ModelForm):
    def clean_date(self):
        user_input = self.cleaned_data.get('date')
        if user_input == 'Today':
            return date.today()
        ...
```

You can read more about Django forms' `clean_<field name>` more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: sweet! Works totally. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CharField, use a DateField and apply the `datetime.today()` in case of Today.

Your code should looks like:

```
models.py
DATE_CHOICES = (
    ('Today', 'Today'),
    ('Other days', 'Other days'),
)

class Mileage(models.Model):
        date = models.DateField('Date')

        def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
            return self.date

    class MileageForm(ModelForm):
        date = forms.DateField()

        class Meta:
            model = Mileage
            fields = ['date']

views.py
from datetime import datetime


def home(request):
form = MileageForm(request.POST or None)

context = {
        "form": form,
    }

if form.is_valid():
    if form.cleaned_data.get('date') == "Today":
        form.cleaned_data["date"]= datetime.today()
    form.save()
    form = MileageForm()
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }

return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```